# Proxy and decorator to prevent setter call on cached objects

Tags: java, proxy

I've been trying to figure out the use of proxy from Javassist to prevent call on setter on any object inside cache. The drawback is that in the curretn application, many object stored in cache don't have interfaces and we need a solution to prevent client to change cached object values Here is my tried solution. What do you think about it.

```
package jp.proof.proxy;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler;
import javassist.util.proxy.Proxy;
import javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory;

public class Immutator {

    private static class Decorator<O extends Object> implements MethodHandler{

        private O o;
        private Decorator(O o) {
            this.o=o;
        }

        private Object invoke(O self, Method methodCall, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Method call: "+methodCall.getName());
            if(methodCall.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Setter is not available");
            }
            return methodCall.invoke(o, args);
        }
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object self, Method thisMethod, Method proceed, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            return this.invoke((O) self, thisMethod, args);
        }
    }

    public static <O extends Object> O immutateProxy(final O o) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
         ProxyFactory f = new ProxyFactory();
         f.setSuperclass(o.getClass());
         Class c = f.createClass();
         Decorator<O> mi = new Decorator<O>(o);
         O foo = (O)c.newInstance();
         ((Proxy)foo).setHandler(mi);
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Here is the cache using the Immutator to proxify every instance it holds:
package jp.proof.proxy;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils;

public class SimpleCache {

    private Map<String,UserVo> users;


    private static SimpleCache instance;

    private SimpleCache() throws Exception {
        users=MapUtils.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
        users.put("Jonathan",Immutator.immutateProxy(new UserVo("Jonathan","Doe")));
        users.put("Alexandre",Immutator.immutateProxy(new UserVo("Alexandre","Doe1")));
        users.put("Manille",Immutator.immutateProxy(new UserVo("Manille","Doe2")));
        users.put("Jules",Immutator.immutateProxy(new UserVo("Jules","Doe3")));
        users.put("Victor",Immutator.immutateProxy(new UserVo("Victor","Doe4")));
    }

    public static SimpleCache getInstance(){
        if(instance==null) {
            try {
                instance=new SimpleCache();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public UserVo getUser(String name){
        return users.get(name);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your comments

Comment: **Update** I've been using this in WebSphere environment (10 ears + load balancing) for about a week without any performance or memory issues.